# Express JS 4.0 command line tool not working

Tags: node.js, express

I was using express 3.x for some time. The command line tool was working perfectly fine. I decided to update to 4.0 so that I can try it out and make old apps to 4.x compatible.

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

installed express perfectly fine, but when I try

```
 exprsss -h
```

I get

```
bash: /usr/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Express 4 seperates the [generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) from express.

What you need to do is to run:

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
```

Then it will work.