# Install express js with npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm installed nodejs on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. When i ran **node --version** it gives me **v4.4.2**. I have install npm with version **3.9.2**. When i run command **npm install -g express** it gives following output
[install express js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Viy.png)

After completing the process, when I try to check express version it tells that **The program 'express' is not installed try apt-get install node-express**. Can somebody tell me where I'm doing wrong

Comment: ExpressJS is not a standalone server. It's meant to be used in a NodeJS application.

Comment: Right. @olivarra1 I've followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps. Please suggest.

Comment: Ahh, I see. As said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468150/express-js-4-0-command-line-tool-not-working, from Express 4 they separated the CLI to the express package itself. You should use now `npm install -g express-generator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, ExpressJS it's a framework for developing servers. It's not a server by itself.

You should create a npm project (with `npm init`) and you can install it as a dependency with `npm install express --save`. Then refer to the "Hello World" example to see how to create a simple server: [Hello World Starter](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Also, you may want to serve static files by using

```
app.use(express.static('name_of_the_directory'));
```

Answer (score 1):

### For install Express  in ubuntu via npm (Follow following steps)

> First open terminal by '**ctrl + alt + t**'
>
> 1. Check nodejs is installed or not by command    :- ***node -v***
> 2. Inter following path into terminal  :- ***cd /var/www/html***
> 3. Create new folder (manually) or by command line :- ***mkdir nodeTest***
> 4. Enter in "nodeTest" folder :- ***cd nodeTest***
> 5. Create 'package.json' :- ***npm init***    //initialize node project (nodeTest)
> 6. install Express :- **sudo npm install express --save**

Now open the 'nodeTest' folder from following path in your system :-   ***/var/www/html/nodeTest***

Now create :- **index.js**

> index.js

```
var express = required("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send(" Welcome Node js ");
});  

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("Node server is runing on port 8000...");
});
```

> Runnig node server by terminal command :- ***node index.js***
>
> Now check url :- "**localhost:8000**"

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're following is outdated.

Previous versions of Express came with a command line tool called `express`, which you could use to create an application skeleton. However, since Express 4 was released (a while ago), this command line tool has been removed from the regular `express` package and moved to a separate package called [`express-generator`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

To install this package, use this:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

This should install the `express` command line tool (however, since the tutorial is outdated you may run into additional problems).